# Como coloco um Json que tem outro json no valor dentro de uma variavel?

Tags: c#, json

Boa noite estou a 2 dias tentando. sem sucesso quero colocar json em variaveis ele le o arquivo como um todo mais nao consigo armazenar em uma variavel

exemplo string nome iria receber jorge string telefone receber "9999999" e a string carro receber "gol" tudo do Json

segue codigo abaixo

arquivo Json

```
{
  "status": {
    "nome": "jorge",
    "telefone": "999999999",
    "carro": "gol" 
        }
     }
```

classe que recebe valores:

```
class Dados
{

    public List<status> msg { get; set; }
}

public class status
{

    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string telefone { get; set; }
    public string carro { get; set; }
   
}
```

classe Program

```
insira o códig  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      StreamReader r = new StreamReader("*/json1.json");
      string json = r.ReadToEnd();
      Dados dados = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dados>(json);
     }
  }
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado ao `Json` apresentado, a estrutura da sua classe para a desserialização está errada. Você não tem uma lista de `msg` refletindo `Status`.

```
public class Dados
{
    public Status Status { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string telefone { get; set; }
    public string carro { get; set; }   
}
```